# Postgresql Unexplained Results - Using timestamptz::date

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, timestamp-with-timezone

PLEASE SEE END OF POST FOR UPDATE.

With reference to the table below, I'm looking to write a query which:

1 - Excludes all rows where bool is set to false

2 - **Casts time (which is a timestamptz) to date (we'll call this 'D')**

3 - Groups by two columns (group and D) and counts the rows

```
group,  time,                               bool
grp-A,  2020-08-28 13:23:00.000000 +00:00,  true 
grp-A,  2020-08-28 10:19:00.000000 +00:00,  false
grp-A,  2020-08-28 09:23:00.000000 +00:00,  true      
grp-B,  2020-08-28 13:51:00.000000 +00:00,  true
grp-B,  2020-08-27 22:35:00.000000 +00:00,  true
grp-B,  2020-08-27 15:10:00.000000 +00:00,  true
grp-B,  2020-08-27 22:06:00.000000 +00:00,  false
grp-A,  2020-08-27 13:03:00.000000 +00:00,  true
```

The answer should be:

```
 group,  time,       count(*)
 grp-A,  2020-08-28, 2  
 grp-B,  2020-08-28, 1
 grp-A,  2020-08-27, 1
 grp-B,  2020-08-27, 2
```

The query I've tried to use is the following:

```
select group, time::date D, count(*)
from table
where bool = True
group by group,D;
```

But it returns the wrong results. The counts are incorrect and it appears to get random/lower numbers.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this? Thank you in advance!

IMPORTANT! EDIT: I've isolated this problem to the `time::date` part of the query. I wrote a new query:

```
select time::date 
from table
```

When I execute this it returns a list of dates but not all of them - only some! Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Your query returns what you would expect:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7670d2cef98462ab0c4f642419208787.

Comment: What is your server timezone?  Issue a `show timezone;` command to see.  Instead of `time::date`, please try `(time at time zone 'utc')::date` to see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Do you mean that `select time::date from table` returns fewer dates then rows in the table? If so it would indicate that the `time` values are `NULL` in some of the rows. You could use `COALESCE(time, some_dummy_time)::date` to get around that. If the preceding is not correct, then you will need to be more specific about 'some'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select grpval, cast(time as date), count(*)
from tablename
where boolval = true
group by grpval, cast(time as date)
```

Comment: More generally, to_char() has formats for any part of the date-time: https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-date-functions/sql-convert-date-to-string-functions/#:~:text=Convert%20date%20to%20string%20using%20TO_CHAR()%20function,a%20date%20as%20a%20string.

Comment: I tried cast(time as date) and to_char() but both produce similarly unexplainable results unfortunately.

Comment: @Ben123, chk here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cfb4997abdcf489ae6f50edf283507d3, it should not produce any  uncertain result